# One-time-only alarms?

Tags: alarm, clock

I would like a way to set one-time-only alarms, that is, alarms that would self delete after being dismissed.

It seems there's no way to do that with the native Clock app by Google (I'm using a Pixel phone). Is there?

Alternatively, do you know any apps on Google Play that have that feature?

Comment: Alternatively, you could set an appointment in Calendar and name it junk. Allow it to go off. And at some future time search for all the junk alarms that you have set and delete them.

Comment: Why do you need it to be removed? I use one-time only alarms - reusing the same one over and over, adjusting it the way I like.

Comment: I currently employ manual alternatives such as these, but it's more clicks. I often setup alarms that I need only once, just for preference, so I figured I would look up a way to do this more easely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the Google Clock app, the alternative is to [set an alarm with Google Assistant](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/9275058?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid#zippy=%2Con-a-phone-or-tablet).

Saying "Set an alarm at [hour] [minutes]" will set a one-time alarm, and it will be automatically removed after dismissing it.